# websocket / stomp connection to ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm trying to connect a webpage with an ActiveMQ via websockets / stomp capabilities. I'm using stomple.js and I getting the following error in the google chrome console:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:61614/stomp' failed: Unexpected response code: 500

The ActiveMQ configuration is as follows:

```
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?transport.closeAsync=false"/>
    <transportConnector name="websockets" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp+nio" uri="stomp+nio://0.0.0.0:61615?transport.closeAsync=false"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

And the javascript I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("pageinit", "#myActiveGamesPage", function () {
        function begin() {
            client.begin({});
        }
        function commit() {
            client.commit({});
        }
        function abort() {
            client.abort({});
        }
        function disconnect() {
            client.disconnect({ success: function () { console.log("dis"); }, failure: function () { console.log(42); } });
        }
        function reset() {
        }
        function sendMsg() {
            var message = 'hola mundo';
            client.send({
                body: client.session + ": " + message,
            });
        }
        if(!Stomple){
            console.log("NO STOMPLE");
        }else{
            console.log("STOMPLE");
            Stomple.debug = true;
            var client = Stomple.create_client({
                url: "ws://localhost:61614/stomp",
                destination: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                login: "guest",
                passcode: "guest",
                socketOpen: function() {
                    console.log("socket opened");
                },
                socketMessage: function(msg) {
                    console.log("socket msg");
                    console.log(msg);
                },
                socketClose: function(e) {
                    console.log("socket close");
                    console.log(e);
                },
                socketError: function() {
                    console.log("socket error");
                    console.log(client.websocket);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            var msgHandler = {
                fn: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg.body);
                }
            };
            client.subscribe({
                handler: msgHandler.fn,
                thisObj: msgHandler,
                success: function() {//did subscription succeed?
                    console.log("sub ok..");
                },
                failure: function(reason) {//did subscription fail?
                    console.log(reason);
                }
            });
        }
});
```

I'm not being able to check what is the client sending to the server (headers) beacuse it is using a binary format and the network tab of the chrome develping tools appears empty.

I have also tried to disable the windows firewall with identical result.

I have not found any documentation of this, and I supose it is not necessary to develop anythig extra in the server because ActiveMQ supply the endpoint and supports the protocol.

Have someone a detailed example of this working or the posible reasons?

Comment: You should be getting something in the activemq logs when you receive a "HTTP" (ok, web socket then) 500 error (typically means internal server error)

Also ws is not a binary format. Your chrome tab "should" show this, since it supports web socket. Otherwise, use something like wireshark if you really want to see the traffic.